# It is possible to define a simple discrete random variable in terms of Bernoulli distributions?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request

It is possible to define a simple discrete random variable in terms of Bernoulli distributions? If the answer to this question is so long or broad I would like to know some bibliography about the topic.

To put my question in a clear context: I have a discrete random variable $X$, that can take values in a finite set $\{z_1,\ldots,z_2\}$ for $z_1,z_2\in\Bbb Z$ (with some PMF $f_X$ defined by a function that maps $z_1\mapsto p_1$ with $p_j\in[0,1]$ and $\sum_j p_j=1$).

Then I want to know if $f_X$ can be written as a composition of Bernoulli random variables, by example as a polynomial of Bernoulli random variables or something similar. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the [Categorical distribution](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Categorical_distribution#/Formulating_distributions):

> A formulation that appears complex but facilitates mathematical manipulations is as follows, using the Iverson bracket:
>
> $$f(x\mid p)=\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_{i}^{[x=i]},$$
>   where [x=i] evaluates to 1 if x=i, 0 otherwise, and $p=(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$. There are various advantages of this formulation, e.g.:
>
> It is easier to write out the likelihood function of a set of independent identically distributed categorical variables.
>
> It connects the categorical distribution with the related multinomial distribution.
>
> It shows why the Dirichlet distribution is the conjugate prior of the categorical distribution, and allows the posterior distribution of the parameters to be calculated.